# hey i am trying to add some test ether to my metamask

Tags: ether, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, goerli

this error 'insufficient funds for gas*price+value

iam using Goerli network and the wallet is metamask
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just search google for goerli faucets. There are many available.
eg.
https://goerlifaucet.com/